# Docker で --network だと環境変数が必要なのに、--link では要らない理由

Tags: mysql, docker, wordpress

Docker Compose を使わずに、DockerでWordpressを実行する方法として
以下のコマンドがあります。

```sh
$ docker run -d --name wpmysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hoge mysql:5.7
$ docker run -d --name wp --link wpmysql:mysql -p 8000:80 wordpress
```

しかし、`--link`は非推奨（レガシー）となったため、
代わりに以下の`--network`を用いたコマンドで実行するのが好ましいようです。

```sh
$ docker network create wp_network

$ docker run -d --name wp_mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hoge \
--net wp_network --expose 3306 \
mysql:5.7

$ docker run -d --name wp -p 8000:80 \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=wp_mysql:3306 \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=hoge \
--net wp_network wordpress
```

`--link` では不要だったのに `--network` で環境変数が必要となるのはなぜか？
お分かりの方いらっしゃったら教えてください。

Comment: `--link` が非推奨であるなら、「`--link` では不要だったのに `--network` で環境変数が必要となるのはなぜか？」の方が質問文としてすっきりしそうな印象です。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。反映しました。